# UITableViewCell is not clickable

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with lot of buttons, textfields, labels and a view. I hide and show them where they are required on each indexpath. But for some reason/s rows are not clickable!

I even have done the following things via code to make sure that if something is going on fishy in IB, it can be fixed via these lines but of no use.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I am wondering if hidden views are the culprit here or something else?

Comment: iOS HIG: *"Apps Respond to Gestures, Not Clicks"* http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Characteristics/Characteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH7-SW4

Comment: @phix23 - Yah but how it is applied in my case?

Comment: set custom object userInteractionEnabled is no

Comment: Can you post the relevant code where you are adding everything to the cell? Knowing where and how you are manipulating each cell would help to debug the issue.

Answer (score 7):

try this  `tableView.allowsSelection=YES;`

and you can implement `-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 3):

I use a lot of different UI elements in my UITableViewCells too, why not try and subclass UITableViewCell and roll your own class, with the items as properties of the cell? Seems to work for me.

**in VincentsAwesomeCell.h:**

```
@interface VincentsAwesomeCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *FooLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *BarLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ShimmyIcon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DooWopLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *UseIcon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TheForceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bobSledIcon;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *WristWatchLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *MeatLoafLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *SciFiLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CollinderLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *RhubarbLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *SuperTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *stepper;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *amountOfAwesomeness;
```

Don't forget to use:

**in VincentsAwesomeCell.m:**

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    // Always call this!
    // Reset custom stuff
}
```

to reset the cells' properties for reuse.

Then in your TableViewController.m:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Register the custom VincentsAwesomeCell NIB with the tableview
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"VincentsAwesomeCell" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"VincentsAwesomeCell"];
}
```

As for the

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I use this for a UIStepper to keep track of which stepper is pressed for example:

```
[[cell stepper]setTag:indexPath.row];
    [[cell stepper]addTarget:self action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Hope this helps!

P.S.

I use a .xib file to create the lay-out of my custom cell. Just drag an UITableViewCell into InterFaceBuilder and customize away! Don't forget to link the properties though!

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for a custom `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell    = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:    [arrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
if (pointRange.location!=NSNotFound) {


    cellImage.frame = CGRectMake(25,12.5, 75, 75);
    lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100);
    lbl.font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"PineappleDemo" size:30.0];
}

lbl.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0/255.0 green:34.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
lbl.text =[arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




for(UIView *v in [cell subviews])
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]||[v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]||[v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [v removeFromSuperview];
}
if (index == indexPath.row) {

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 90, tableView.frame.size.width-200, 100)];
     lbl2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     lbl2.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl2.text = [arrayOffers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:lbl2];
    [lbl2 release];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width-150, 100, 120, 84);
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (indexPath.row<=2) {
        switch (indexPath.row ) {
            case 0:
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lickFB.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(facebook) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;
            case 1:
                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"follow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(twitter) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;
            case 2:

                [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rateUs.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(rateAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    else{
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Buy_Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 3:
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deal1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;
            case 4:
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deal2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;
            case 5:
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deal3) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;

            case 6:
                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(deal4) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                break;



            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    [cell addSubview:btn];

}

[cell addSubview:lbl];
[cell addSubview:cellImage];
[cellImage release];
[lbl release];
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table view is editable, this might be the reason why cells are not clickable

If that's the case and you do need cells to be clickable while editing - simply do this:

```
tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

Comment: I may sound stupid to you but where I can see if tableview is editable or not?

Comment: By default table view is not editable. The easy way to see is that when table is in editing mode, you will see minus sign in red circle, or plus sign in green circle next to table cells. You can make table editable setting "editing" property to TRUE, but you should also implement some additional methods in order to define editing style and handle editing itself, you can read about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW58

Answer (score 1):

In your custom UITableViewCell, do you add btn, textfields, etc to contentView?

Maybe if you add everything to contentView, that should solve your problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Please share some code. How are you creating the custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot really make the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" triggering properly, put a BIG UIButton occupying full cell and do the necessary actions in button click. Just an idea! :-)

Comment: Thanks. But it's not possible as there are text fields in the cell.

Comment: No problem, you can have the button behind all control elements, so that it will trigger only when there is no other elements to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Solved it but adding

```
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

to the view, on which my tableView is located. So I determined, that my tableView was beyond the frame of its parent view.